# C++ memory leak when creating an array

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

In my C++ game I have an array of pointers to `EnemyType`s. I used Visual Leak Detector to detect memory leaks, and it's telling me I have a leak in the following piece of code:

```
vector<EnemyType*> enemyTypes(number_of_lines);

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++)
{
    enemyTypes[i] = new EnemyType();
}
```

Let's say `number_of_lines` is 3 in this case. How is it possible that I'm creating a leak right here? Can I do something about it?

I started learning C++ about a month ago and I'm still learning every day, but I cannot understand some things (like this) without someone explaining me.

**EDIT:** I have modified the code to use a vector instead of a plain array.

Comment: Did you tried vectors?

Comment: You only create a leak when you forget to free the memory.  The code above does not show this problem.  Create an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If `enemyTypes` is local to a method and you don't `delete` each element (and the array itself) then you have a leak. Consider using a `std::vector<EnemyType>`, dynamic memory is not always desiderable, and when used, proper smart pointers could leverage the management part.

Comment: It's a game I'm making for school and it's not yet allowed to use smart pointers. I've considered using a vector, but using a plain array seemed better for learning purposes, but I'll reconsider using it now.

Comment: Is there a reason that you use pointers? You can also store the EnemyType in the array (or even better: in a vector).

Answer (score 2):

From your original code:

```
EnemyType** enemyTypes{ new EnemyType*[number_of_lines] };

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++)
{
    enemyTypes[i] = new EnemyType();
}
```

When you allocate memory in C++ using `new`, you have to deallocate it using `delete` (or `delete[]` when you allocated an array, like your `enemyTypes`).

We see only part of your code, but I guess you're not doing any deallocation when you don't need the memory anymore.

By the way, you should just avoid allocating memory, or allocate it through managed pointers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// ...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<EnemyType>> enemy_types(number_of_lines);

for (auto& enemy_type : enemy_types)
{
    enemy_type = std::make_unique<EnemyType>();
}
```

Depending on how you use your data, you can even avoid pointers:

```
std::vector<EnemyType> enemy_types(number_of_lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

Operator `new` dynamically allocates memory.

Some code, eventually, needs to release that memory using the corresponding operator `delete`.     If your code does not do that, the memory is never released.    That becomes a leak if your program loses track (e.g. the pointer used to hold the result of the `new` ceases to exist).

A slightly modified version of your code

```
int func()
{
    EnemyType** enemyTypes{ new EnemyType*[number_of_lines] };

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++)
    {
         enemyTypes[i] = new EnemyType();
    }
}
```

The pointer `enemyTypes` ceases to exist (since it passes out of scope) as the function returns.   A consequence is that the memory created with the first usage of operator `new` is never released AND no pointer exists which points to it.    Since that memory cannot be accessed, the results of operator `new` in the loop also cannot be accessed (since the only place those results are stored is in the dynamically allocated array identified by `enemyTypes`).

All that memory is therefore leaked at that point (the dynamically allocated memory cannot be recovered by your program, unless you use some technique outside the bounds of standard C++).  Various memory checkers - if you use them - will report a leak accordingly .... either at the point where the function returns, or when the program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

When using the operator new, verify that you delete each object that you created.

A good alternative could be using smart pointers from STL or boost library. They will delete automatically your object when it became unused, thus avoiding memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was never releasing the memory (as other people told me), but Visual Leak Detector just showed me where this memory was allocated and not where the leak happened.